# Get length of an array returned by firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

The usual .length property of the array doesn't work on the arrays returned by firebase. Here is the console.log of the returned array:

```
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
$$added: function () { [native code] }
$$error: function () { [native code] }
$$moved: function () { [native code] }
$$removed: function () { [native code] }
$$updated: function () { [native code] }
$add: function () { [native code] }
$destroy: function () { [native code] }
$getRecord: function () { [native code] }
$indexFor: function () { [native code] }
$inst: function () { [native code] }
$keyAt: function () { [native code] }
$loaded: function () { [native code] }
$remove: function () { [native code] }
$save: function () { [native code] }
$watch: function () { [native code] }
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
concat: function concat() { [native code] }
constructor: function Array() { [native code] }
every: function every() { [native code] }
filter: function filter() { [native code] }
findIndex: function (a){if(null==this)throw new TypeError("Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined");if("function"!=typeof a)throw new TypeError("predicate must be a function");for(var b,c=Object(this),d=c.length>>>0,e=arguments[1],f=0;d>f;f++)if(f in c&&(b=c[f],a.call(e,b,f,c)))return f;return-1}
forEach: function forEach() { [native code] }
indexOf: function indexOf() { [native code] }
join: function join() { [native code] }
lastIndexOf: function lastIndexOf() { [native code] }
length: 0
map: function map() { [native code] }
pop: function pop() { [native code] }
push: function push() { [native code] }
reduce: function reduce() { [native code] }
reduceRight: function reduceRight() { [native code] }
reverse: function reverse() { [native code] }
shift: function shift() { [native code] }
slice: function slice() { [native code] }
some: function some() { [native code] }
sort: function sort() { [native code] }
splice: function splice() { [native code] }
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
unshift: function unshift() { [native code] }
```

even the console.log length property shows 5 but for some reason calling the length property returns 0.

**Edit:**

The length property of the array is set to 5 but the length property of the **proto** is 0. The .length property returns the 0 value under the **proto** .

Comment: Please output your `$scope.Notes` to the console and show a snapshot of it, that would help

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular Js?

Comment: if it returns 0, it definitely is empty.  Select isn't broken (http://pragmatictips.com/26)

Comment: Did you try official documentation? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#firebasearray

Comment: @J.Wells It is an angular app.

Comment: @xtofl No it is not empty. Console.log shows that.

Comment: @PSL yep I tried the official docs but I couldn't find anything useful there related to this issue.

Comment: The `$scope.Notes.length` might be called too early.

Comment: @runTarm I added a delay time but it didn't work :(

Comment: @J.Wells He is using AngulareFire which is Firebase's realtime data sync library for AngularJS.

Comment: @Khashayar.P I understand it's an angular app, but there wasn't any angular code. Also - it would appear that it turned out to be a firebase thing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Keep in mind that calling `$asArray` is an asynchronous action.

```
$scope.notes = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
console.log($scope.notes.length); // the data has not loaded yet
```

The reason why you're seeing a zero length in the console is because values can change between buffering of the log and printing it, which can be very misleading. Try using a breakpoint to see the values as they execute.

Since the data is asynchronous you'll need to use the `$loaded` promise.

```
$scope.notes.$loaded().then(function(notes) {
   console.log(notes.length); // data is loaded here
});
```

Comment: How can the length value displayed in the DOM? will it be updated every without adding watch ?

Comment: Thank you David for your help )