# How to obtain the ng-repeat length using innerItem?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have this issue... I'm using ng-repeat with inner to obtain the data inside a child, this works perfectly but I cannot find the method to get the length of the ng-repeat. I need to get the count of the comments.

How to obtain the ng-repeat length using inner?:

```
   js:
    angular.module('myApp.Profile', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])
   .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/Profile', {
   templateUrl: 'Profile/Profile.html',
   controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
   });
   }])

.controller('ProfileCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', function ($scope, $firebase, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {

   var firebaseRefs = firebase.database().ref('PostUsers/');
   $scope.PostList = $firebaseArray(firebaseRefs);

   }]);


   html:
  <body ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="PostList in PostList"> 

  <p>Author: {{PostList.userAuthor}}</p> 
  <p>Comments: {{PostList.post}}</p> 

  <div ng-repeat="innerPostList in PostList.PostedComments">

   <p>Author: {{innerPostList.username}}</p>
    <p>Comments:{{innerPostList.comments}}</p> 

 </div> 
</div> 

 <h4>Publications number: {{PostList.length}}</h4>
<h4>Comments number: {{????.length}}</h4> 

</body>
```

I'm using Firebase:

[image]

NOTE:{{ PostList.PostedComments.length}} is not working...

this error appears when I try this in the controller:
 angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
This is what I did:

var value = PostList.PostedComments.length;

console.log('the comments value is:' + value);

but when I try this it works fine:

var value = PostList.length;

console.log('the comments value is:' + value);

Comment: note: this is the firebase ref:                                                                               js:                                                                                                               var firebaseRefs = firebase.database().ref('PostUsers/'); $scope.PostList = $firebaseArray(firebaseRefs);

Comment: Why can't you just do `<h4>{{PostList.PostedComments.length}}</h4>` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can ng-repeat on `PostList.PostedComments`, theres no reason you can't just grab the length from it directly.

```
<div ng-repeat="innerPostList in PostList.PostedComments">
   <p>{{innerPostList.comments}}</p>
</div>

<!-- length -->
<h4>{{PostList.PostedComments.length}}</h4>
```

EDIT: I just did some research on firebase and it seems that your $firebaseArray() returns a promise-like wrapper for the actual data/results, so thats probably why it doesn't directly have the properties on it that you want. Its also possible that the network request/ promise hasn't resolved yet when you are inspecting it.

Instead of  `var firebaseRefs = firebase.database().ref('PostUsers/');
          $scope.PostList = $firebaseArray(firebaseRefs);`

Try something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('PostUsers/').$loaded().then(function(data) {
   $scope.PostList = data;
});
```

Inspect the data object and make sure it has what you want.

Useful references:

- [How to loop through $firebaseArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061790/how-to-loop-through-firebasearray)
- https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html
- [Get length of an array returned by firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340931/get-length-of-an-array-returned-by-firebase)
- http://lisukun.me/?p=125

Comment: technically it should work. What happens when you capture the length in the controller and do a console.log for that. Do you see an error?

Comment: this error appears when I try this in the controller: angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined,                             this is what I did:                                                                                    var value = PostList.PostedComments.length;
console.log('the comments value is:' + value);                                                 but when I try this it works fine:                                                                 var value = PostList.length;
console.log('the comments value is:' + value);

Comment: PostList is contaning the firebaseArray as expected but PostList.PostedComments is undefined...

Comment: I removed the PostedComments from PostList,PostedComments and it is actually also containing the firebaseArray : PostList.length